# pfSense: Allow VLAN Access to all but WAN

Tags: firewall, pfsense

I have machines in a VLAN and I need to have them access all but not get out to the internet.

I have tried this (and lots of others options) but nothing is working.
[image]
I simply need to block internet access and allow all other access.

From how I understand this rule to work all access except WAN network should be Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

outbound traffic still needs to be specifically blocked, the default deny rule only applies to inbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

OK fixed by explicitly allow only internal traffic by listing all networks in an Alias and then associating the alias to an allow rule. All else was by default blocked.